# Tornado gen.coroutine gen.Task

Tags: python, tornado

refresh() can be called from main(), refreshloop() on the other hand looks like it doesn't start. I want refreshloop() to call refresh() periodically. What am I doing wrong here?

```
count = 0
mainloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
stoprloop = False

@gen.coroutine
def refreshloop(interval):
    global mainloop
    count += 1
    print "here  #" + str(count)
    next_time = mainloop.current().time()
    while (stoprloop == False):
        next_time += int(interval)
        refresh()
        while next_time <= mainloop.current().time():
            next_time += int(interval)
        yield gen.Task(mainloop.current().call_at, next_time)

def main():
    global mainloop

    ...

    refresh()
    refreshloop(5)
    mainloop.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**____edit_____________________________________________________________________**

Thank you both!

An imported script was available only locally and the resulting error hasn't been displayed.

**____edit_____________________________________________________________________**

And both solutions seem to work perfectly :).

```
refreshloop(5)

mainloop.add_callback(refreshloop, 5)
```

Comment: Your code works for me if I replace the call to "refresh()" with "print 'refresh'". Perhaps there's something in the contents of the "refresh" function that will help me diagnose your problem?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis even if we'll remove `refresh()` from `main()`, `refreshloop` will not be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just call coroutine directly, you need to add it as [callback to ioloop](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback):

```
def main():
    global mainloop

    ...

    refresh()
    mainloop.add_callback(refreshloop, 5)
    mainloop.start()
```

Comment: This isn't correct. You can call a coroutine directly and it runs until it hits its first "yield". Then if you start the IOLoop as the questioner demonstrated, the coroutine continues to run. Using "addcallback" here hasn't answered the question.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis but in question there is no `yield`, and adding coroutine as callback solves the problem, i.e. `refreshloop` will be called. Agree, coroutine may be called directly, but what is wrong with provided code? If we'll remove calling `refresh()` entirely, `refreshloop` will not be called anyway.